# LDAP Account Manager file upload is not working

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have a problem with the file upload in the LDAP account manager. It just generates an empty webpage with not message at all. Before my I updated from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 it worked an either stated that the entries were made or if an error occured. Did anyone encountered the same problem?

Best regards